# How to capture mouse cursor location over my uploaded image in html and php?

Tags: php, html, image, mouseover

I just want to write text over my uploaded image. I am using only html and php.
For the same, I am trying to save the position of the mouse cursor where the user clicks on the image to write his text.
I have tried these things below.
It shows error in my click.php.

1. index.php

   ```
   <form action="click.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <h3>Select image to upload:<br/></h3>
       <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" accept="image/*"/>
       <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit"/>
   </form>
   ```
2. click.php

   ```
       <script>
       function getPos(e){
           x=e.clientX;
           y=e.clientY;
           cursor="Your Mouse Position Is : " + x + " and " + y ;
           document.getElementById("displayArea").innerHTML=cursor
       }

       function stopTracking() {
           document.getElementById("displayArea").innerHTML="";
       }
       </script>

       <div id="focusArea" onmousemove="getPos(event)" onmouseout="stopTracking()">
       <?php
           $target_dir = "uploads/";
           $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
             //Set the Content Type
           header("Content-type: image/png");
             #dispaly the image
           $file = $_POST['file'];
           echo file_get_contents($file);
       ?>
       </div>
       <p id="displayArea"></p>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

**Please try this**

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#A').click(function(e) {
        alert(e.pageX+ ' , ' + e.pageY);
    });    
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/AMsK9/722/)

Comment: Can we draw a round or a shape on particular area on that uploaded image ? and save that area in MySQL database ? I tried canvas, but couldnt help me !

Comment: @Hytool You need to add the positions clicked to an array and then insert it

Comment: @RinoRaj u suggested me the way using javascript. I am bounded to use only php and html. Please suggest me ways in the same.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, User wont be clicking on the uploaded image, user will drag the mouse and draw the shape on the image, and I want to store that shape in database and want to fetch that shape back on the uploaded image on request.

Comment: @Hytool http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-mouse-co-ordinates-mouseover-click-within-element/

Comment: ok, Mouse position within element on mouseover could be useful, I will have to capture all the positions into array and save it in DB, right ?  I will now discover how to draw line with mouseover. Thanks Rino !